# Facebook contest policy no-no?

Tags: facebook, links

I would like to post a link on a Facebook page where it will exit Facebook entirely and go to a client's website, where people will be on a page (client's) where they can enter their e-mail address to be entered in a temporary database file with rules and disclosures etc., for a draw once the number of entries reaches 100 for instance.

Once the number of entries reaches 100, a random winner is picked and notified via E-mail.

The functionality is as follows:

- A link is place on a Facebook page leading to an external page
- The page is a form to merely enter their email address for a
  contest
- The email is placed in a temporary file
- An automatic E-mail is sent to the address used for confirmation
  using SHAH-256 hash
- The person receives the Email saying something to the affect
  "Please confirm your Email address etc. - If you did not authorize
  this, simply ignore this message and no further action will be
  taken".
- If the person clicks on the confirmation link, the Email is then
  stored in the database and the person is again notified saying "Thank
  you for signing up etc."
- Once others do the same process and the database reaches a certain
  number, the form is no longer accessible and automatically picks a
  random Email.
- Once picked, an Email is automatically sent to the winner stating
  the instructions, and notifying me also.
- Once that person clicks yet another confirmation link, the
  database is then automatically deleted.

I have built this myself and have no intentions of breaking any rules, nor jeopardize the work/time/energy I have put into this project.

Is this allowed?

Comment: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @JohnConde Is this a fit for move to facebook.so? It's more policy than actually code-related, but I never go over there(or FB, for that matter), so don't know.

Comment: @Christofian That's what I was thinking, but from what I have read on Facebook as well as on other sites, seems unclear. For instance in section 4.2 In the rules of the promotion, or otherwise, you will not condition entry to the promotion upon taking any action on Facebook, for example, `updating a status`, posting on a profile or Page etc. It's the `status` thing that bewilders me.

Comment: @Fred can you post a link to the rules that make you think that this would break one?

Comment: @Christofian http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/12/31/policy-watch-facebook-page-owners-can-require-users-to-become-fans-in-order-to-enter-contests/

Comment: @Fred what they mean by that is that you can't make the user post a status update on facebook in order to be participate in a competition/promotion.

Comment: @Su' it could be ontopic on webapps.se, though I'm not positive about that.

Comment: @Christofian Then I'm ok then. See.. I got the complete opposite of their meaning, and is so confusing. It's a "should've gone to law school" to understand their policies. Thanks, cheers~

Comment: @to_whom_it_may_concern - If this was not the place to post my question, then would like to know where I could post another question, should the occasion ever present itself, again.

Answer (score 5):

I just read an article about this on hubspot. http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/33589/40-Ways-to-Get-Banned-From-the-Top-5-Social-Networks.aspx

If I correctly understand what you're doing, the only problem I see is that it is not using a Facebook app for the contest.